# What is the yum equivalent of dpkg -L?

Tags: linux, yum, rhel6, dpkg, scientific-linux

`dpkg -L` lists all the files provided by a package. How is this accomplished with **yum**?

The operating system is Scientific Linux 6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This functionality is provided by **rpm**, not yum:

`rpm -ql [packagename]`

From the [documentation](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/rpm.8.html#AEN17034):

> The general form of an rpm query command is
>
> ```
>  rpm {-q | --query} [PACKAGE_NAME] [query-options]
> ```
>
> Information selection options:
>
> ```
>  -l, --list
>      List files in package.
> ```

Comment: @catpants: More generally, yum is to apt-get, as rpm is to dpkg.

Answer (score 9):

`rpm -ql packagename` is roughly equivalent.

You should think of `yum` as similar to `apt-get` and `rpm` as roughly equivalent to `dpkg`.  `yum` deals with packages in terms of repositories, and `rpm` deals with individual packages.

Ubuntu actually provides a cheat sheet on similar actions:

[Switching between RedHat and Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwitchingToUbuntu/FromLinux/RedHatEnterpriseLinuxAndFedora)